# Showing documents from a sharepoint document library as attachments inside a DataCard

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-portal

We have a SharePoint custom list named "Grant Applications" and document library named "Attachments". We are showing the related documents from the document library inside the custom list form, as follow:-

[image]

here is the formula for the datacard

[image]

[image]

and the "collAttachmentsGranteeFormSaved" is been populated as follow:-

```
ClearCollect(
collAttachmentsGranteeFormSaved,
Filter(
Attachments,
ItemId = Value(varId),
Category.Value = "Monitoring And Evaluation Plan"
)
);
```

but when we click on an attachment file , we will get this error:

[image]
any advice?